# DiffUtil.calculateDiff In RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this code below which uses the DiffUtil.calculateDiff between two lists. Each time i scroll further down the list, new data comes and added to the list. But when the result notifies changes, the adapter leads me to the top of the list each time.

1. How can i  remain to the position which the new data was added?
2. This example is the right usage of DiffUtil.calculateDiff?or  simply do i need to use :

   ```
   companyList.addAll(companies);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

without the DiffUtil.calculateDiff.

```
public void setProductList(final List<? extends Product> productList) {
    if (mProductList == null) {
        mProductList = productList;
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, productList.size());
    } else {
        DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return mProductList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return productList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return mProductList.get(oldItemPosition).getId() ==
                        productList.get(newItemPosition).getId();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                Product newProduct = productList.get(newItemPosition);
                Product oldProduct = mProductList.get(oldItemPosition);
                return newProduct.getId() == oldProduct.getId()
                        && Objects.equals(newProduct.getDescription(), oldProduct.getDescription())
                        && Objects.equals(newProduct.getName(), oldProduct.getName())
                        && newProduct.getPrice() == oldProduct.getPrice();
            }
        });
        mProductList.addAll(productList);
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new list should contain both your existing items and new. So the old list should be a copy of `mProductList` before you append the new items, and the new list should be `mProductList` after appending `productList`. But if you're not concerned about the existing items changing at all and are just appending to the list rather than sorting/filtering, you can probably just do the work with `notifyItemRangeInserted` without using `DiffUtil`, in which case your else block would be:

```
int insertIndex = mProductList.size();
mProductList.addAll(productList);
notifyItemRangeInserted(insertIndex, productList.size());
```